# Install pandas v.0.13 (dev version) in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pip

How can I install pandas dev version in my Python 2.7 (and OS X 10.9 and pip 1.4.1 for your information).

When I installed pandas using pip, the installed version is v.0.12 (latest stable version) for sure. However, when I cloned the repository from Github and installed it using `setup.py`, the installed version is also v.0.12. So is it feasible to install v.0.13 under my system, and if it is, how can I do?

I don't want to use Scipy Superpack, which would install the dev version, since I like to install the dev version only on pandas, not on numpy, scipy, etc... as well.

I also want to install it under my Python 3.3 if it's feasible, but would be glad to accept it only on Python 2.7.

Thanks.

Comment: For your last request, assuming you've installed `setuptools` and `pip` properly for your Python 3.3 (which you get for free with, e.g., Homebrew, but not with python.org binary installers), just do the exact same thing twice, but with `pip` and `pip3`, or `pip-2.7` and `pip-3.3`.

Comment: Yeah, I use it to install third-party libraries in my Python 3.x system. I just meant that it can be acceptable even if the potential solution does only work in Python 2.7 (such as Scipy Superpack, which only works for system built-in Python version in OS X), but would be glad to also get it installed in Python 3.

Comment: Important note: pandas 0.24.x releases will be the last to support Python 2!
[pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html)

Answer (score 3):

Pandas v0.13.0 isn't out yet, and the [GitHub repo still shows it as 0.12.0 within setup.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/2d7514f61126e1eb8aef2e232a7a7b60a7697412/setup.py#L191-L198) at the time of this writing:

```
MAJOR = 0
MINOR = 12
MICRO = 0
ISRELEASED = False
VERSION = '%d.%d.%d' % (MAJOR, MINOR, MICRO)
QUALIFIER = ''

FULLVERSION = VERSION
```

However, if you want to install a specific version of pandas (or any package), you can typically specify it:

```
$ pip install pandas==0.12.0
```

If you want to install straight from master on GitHub (which can be a scary beast), you can also do this directly:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/pydata/pandas.git
```

Hopefully you've installed setuptools and pip appropriately.

For python3, switch to pip3 (or pip-3.2, etc.). If you set python3 as the default within a virtualenv, pip is for python3:

```
$ mkvirtualenv --python=python3.2 tardis
...
(tardis) $ pip install pandas
```

Comment: So there are no means to install it at this time (other than those at dev teams)?

Comment: @user2360798: If it doesn't exist, then obviously you can't install it. If it _does_ exist, you can install it via `git+https`, as the answer already says.

Comment: You can see the bleeding latest in the repo right now. If there's a time travel setting for pip, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: @KyleKelley: Didn't you watch Day of the Doctor on Saturday? Time travel is a lot easier now than it was a couple days ago.

Comment: `pip install pandas==0.13.0 --proxy heart-of-the-tardis`?

Comment: There are no distributions for v0.13, unfortunately. And I just found that Scipy Superpack doesn't provide v0.13 (it provided the dev version in the past). So I decided to wait for a few more weeks or months to finally get it installed in my system. Thanks you guys!

Comment: And what you guys mean in `time travel setting` and `Day of the Doctor on Saturday`?

Comment: @user2360798: It's an extended joke. The bleeding-edge dev version is 0.12.0. You want 0.13.0. Given that it doesn't exist yet, the only way you can get that is to time-travel to the future. "Day of the Doctor" was the 50th anniversary special of Doctor Who, which is a show about time travel; by using the time machine from that show, the TARDIS, as a proxy, you can get code from the future. (But really, why not just `pip install the-code-i-was-planning-to-write-next-year --proxy heart-of-the-tardis` and save yourself the effort of writing it?)

Comment: The Day of The Doctor was the title of an episode of the British Science Fiction television show, Doctor Who. The release date 23 November, 2013 was also the 50th anniversary of the series itself. Also, we're switching to the 12th doctor soon. (Well, 13th, which only makes this more silly)